# ImageMagick -format argument No decode delegate

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-identify

I am getting errors when trying to use the format argument in any command, I tried to espace the using backslashes like this `\"%m:%f %wx%h\"` but it doesn't work either

I am running on a MAC M1, not sure if it could impact

Example

```
identify -units PixelsPerInch -format "%m:%f %wx%h"  238d99c5-8b58-46c7-ac94-b28b3898b8b8.jpeg
```

And I get

```
identify: unable to open image '%m:%f %wx%h': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3570. 
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
```

I checked the decodes installed and jpeg is there

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-51 Q16-HDRI aarch64 20499 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(5.0) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw tiff webp xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (4.2)
```

Comment: If using v7, your command should be `magick identify ...`, surely? Try changing the double quotes around `"%m:%f %wx%h"` to single quotes in case there is some weird interaction with your shell. You don't need your shell to interpolate anything in there anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling everything again and restarting the computer, suddenly it started working